# Adding a property to an Html template gives error "Object does not allow properties to be added or changed"

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, dialog, template-engine

I am trying to retrieve the data from my Google Spreadsheet, but when I try to add the `data` object to my `htmlTemplate` object, I receive the error

> 'Object does not allow properties to be added or changed'

My code is pretty simple:

```
function showDialog() {
  var htmlTemplate = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index');

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();
  var values = range.getValues(); //get the spreadsheet data

  htmlTemplate.data = values; // error here
  ...
}
```

Could anyone tell me what is wrong with this?

Comment: What are you trying to do? As the error indicates, you are not allowed to add properties to Google's native classes.

Comment: Please review the [HTML Service: Templated HTML](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates) guide, try to apply that, and then update us & your question if you are still having problems. (We'll need to see your index.html file and maybe a screenshot of your spreadsheet, too.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of [createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/html-service#createhtmloutputfromfilefilename) use [createTemplateFromFile(filename)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/html-service#createTemplateFromFile(String))

The above because the first returns a HtmlOutput object which not allow to add properties while the second returns a HtmalTemplate which allows to add properties.

Reference

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates

Answer (score 5):

You can't add properties once you have already created the htmlOutput, rather you should populate properties in a template and then evaluate that template so that properties are consumed[if you're consuming] and then final htmlOutput is produced.

In terms of code something like this :

```
function showDialog() {
  //Create a template
  var htmlTemplate = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('index');

  //Fetch the data
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[0].getDataRange().getValues();

  //Plug in those data in template
  htmlTemplate.data = values;

  //Finally evaluate the template, to produce the actually html from the template
  var htmlOutput = htmlTemplate.evaluate();

  //Return [if required]
  return htmlOutput;
}
```