# Google Apps Script, Google Sheet - Template Scriplets don't work

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've been reading these answers and trying out some of the code, but I could not get my code to work.  These are the links I've been reading:

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs#page.html_1
- [How to pass a parameter to html?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30033459/how-to-pass-a-parameter-to-html/38314034#38314034)
- [Adding a property to an Html template gives error "Object does not allow properties to be added or changed"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49725049/adding-a-property-to-an-html-template-gives-error-object-does-not-allow-propert)

My Code.gs:

```
function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or SlidesApp or FormApp.
      .createMenu('Custom Menu')
      .addItem('Show sidebar', 'showSidebar')
      .addToUi();
}
function showSidebar() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Page')
      .setTitle('My custom sidebar');
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or SlidesApp or FormApp.
      .showSidebar(html);
}
function testCSV2() {
  const text = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getDataRange().getDisplayValues();
  const result = cellArraysToCsv(text);
  Logger.log(result);
  return result;
}
function cellArraysToCsv(data) {
  const regex = /"/g;
  let change = data.map(row => row.map(value => `"${value.replace(regex, '\"\"')}"`)).join('\n');
  return change;
}
```

My Page.html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<script>
  function answers() {
    var data = google.script.run.testCSV2();
    document.getElementById("myTitle").innerText = data;
  }
</script>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    Hello, world! <input type="button" value="Answers" onclick="answers()" />
    <H2 id="myTitle"></H2><br><br>
    <?!= testCSV2() ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

I'm getting very confused.  Why is it that when I click on the button "Answers", I get no output?  And why is `<?!= testCSV2() ?>` unchanged in the `<body>` of Page.html?

[image: My Sidebar Output]

Comment: `And why is <?!= testCSV2() ?> unchanged in the <body> of Page.html?` Because you didn't `createTemplateFromFile()` but created `HtmlOutput` directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Description**

There are two part to this.  Using templated HTML in which `testCSV2()` is run on the server as well as passing `data` before the HTML is displayed and using `google.script.run.testCSV3()` to get data from the server.

**Code.gs**

```
function onOpen() {
  var menu = SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu("Test");
  menu.addItem("Show Test", "showSidebar").addToUi();
}

function showSidebar() {
  var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("HTML_Test");
  html.data = "greetings";
  html = html.evaluate();
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(html);
}

function testCSV2() {
  return "hello";
}

function testCSV3() {
  return "goodbye";
}
```

**HTML_Test**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    Hello, world! <input type="button" value="Answers" onclick="answers()" />
    <H2 id="myTitle"></H2><br><br>
    <?!= data ?><br>
    <?!= testCSV2() ?>
    <script>
      function answers() {
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler( 
          function (data) {
            document.getElementById("myTitle").innerText = data;
          }
        ).testCSV3();
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**References**

- [Templated HTML](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates#code.gs_1)
- [google.script.run](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run)

Comment: You provided a working example, but you didn't describe what's wrong with OP's code.

Comment: What do you mean? He's using `createHtmlOutputFromFile` when he should be using templated HTML as I've shown.

Comment: That part is not clear. Unless one compares code and tries to figure out the difference, that part is not obvious. Personally, I think, if you only highlighted that in plain english even without any code, the answer would be  perfect. Just my two cents.

Comment: I did in my description "Using templated HTML" and by reference.

Answer (score 1):

```
google.script.run.yourfunctionName();
```

Use this code in JavaScript to call your function that's defined in gs file.

**Reference:** [Communicate with server function](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication#index.html_1)

Comment: Thanks, but now the output is `undefined`.  And `<?!= testCSV2() ?>` is still unchanged in the `<body>` of Page.html.  Something's still wrong..  Changed code: `var data = google.script.run.testCSV2();`

Comment: update answers function with this code google.script.run.withSuccessHandler( 
          function (data) {
            document.getElementById("myTitle").innerText = data;
          }
        ).testCSV2();